# How to draw this figures in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
    
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [->] (0,0)--(5,0) node[right]{$X$};
    \draw [->] (0,0)--(0,5) node[above]{$Y$};
    \draw[thick]  (4,0)--node [right] {$P(r,\theta)$}(2.5,4);
    \node at (4,-0.3){$L$};
    \node at (0,-0.3) {$O$};
    \draw[thick] (0,0) -- node [left] {$r$}(3.5,4) ;
    \draw (3,3) arc (-35:-120:0.5);
    \draw (3.3,3.3) arc (0:120:0.5);
    \draw (1,0) arc (0:45:1);      
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

What it should look like:

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) On this site, a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this table?"). Questions that look like "Please do this complicated thing for me" tend to get closed because they are either "off topic", "too broad", or "unclear". Please try to make your question clear and simple by giving a [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228): you'll stand a greater chance of getting help.

Comment: Welcome to the site -- please have a look at the answer below if it meets the requirement-- please revert for any problem

Answer (score 15):

If you have a lot of figures like that then  `tkz-euclide` can help you

```
\documentclass{standalone} 
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tkzInit[xmax=6, ymax=6]
\tkzDefPoints{0/0/O,5/0/L,4/5/M,6/0/x}
\tkzDrawX[label=$X$] \tkzDrawY[label=$Y$]
\tkzDrawLines[add=0 and 0.4](O,M L,M)
\tkzLabelSegment(O,M){$r$}
\tkzLabelSegment(M,L){$P(r,\theta)$}
\tkzDefPointOnLine[pos=1.2](O,M) \tkzGetPoint{m1}
\tkzDefPointOnLine[pos=1.2](L,M) \tkzGetPoint{m2}
\tkzMarkAngles[<->](L,O,M O,M,L x,L,M m1,M,m2) 
\tkzLabelAngle[pos=1.2](L,O,M){$\theta$}
\tkzLabelAngle[pos=1.2](O,M,L){$\beta$}
\tkzLabelAngle[pos=1.2](x,L,M){$\Phi$}
\tkzLabelAngle[pos=1.2](m1,M,m2){$\beta$}
\tkzLabelPoints(O,L)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: excellent use of tkz-euclide  +1

Answer (score 9):

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles, quotes, intersections}

\begin{document}

       \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw [->]  (0,0)   coordinate[label=below:${O}$]   (origin)--
                    (5,0)   coordinate[label=right:${X}$]   (x);
        \draw [->]  (0,0)--
                    (0,5)   coordinate[label=above:${Y}$]   (y);
        \draw[thick, name path=ll1]         
                    (4,0)   coordinate[label=below:${L}$](l)--
                    node [right] {$P(r,\theta)$}(2.5,4) coordinate(l1);

        \draw[thick, name path=rr1] 
                    (0,0) -- 
                    node [left] {$r$}(3.5,4) coordinate(r1) ;

        \pic [draw, 
                thick, 
                <->,
                angle radius=8mm,
                angle eccentricity=1.3,
                "$\theta$"]     {angle = x--origin--r1};
        \pic [draw, 
                thick, 
                <->,
                angle radius=6mm,
                angle eccentricity=1.3,
                "$\phi$"]     {angle = x--l--l1};

        \path [name intersections={of=rr1 and ll1, by=p}];

        \pic [draw, 
                thick, 
                <->,angle radius=6mm,
                angle eccentricity=1.3,
                "$\beta$"]     {angle = r1--p--l1};
        \pic [draw, 
                thick, 
                <->,
                angle radius=6mm,
                angle eccentricity=1.4,
                "$\beta$"]     {angle = origin--p--l};


    
       \end{tikzpicture}          

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

A small variation of nice @js bibra answer (+1):

- common style for all angles,
- used are polar coordinates

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles, arrows.meta, 
                intersections,
                quotes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
           > = {Straight Barb[scale=0.8]},
Angle/.style = {draw, <->,
                angle radius=5mm,
                angle eccentricity=1.3,
                font=\scriptsize},
every edge quotes/.append style = {inner sep=1pt,text depth=0.5ex, pos=0.35}
                        ]
% axis
\draw [->]  (-0.4,0) -- (5,0) coordinate[label=below left:$x$] (x);
\draw [->]  (0,-0.4) -- (0,5) coordinate[label=below left:$y$] (y);
% triangle
\draw[semithick, name path=A]
    (0,0)   coordinate[label=below left:O] (o)
            to ["$r$"] ++ (45:4.9) coordinate (r1);
\draw[semithick, name path=B]
    (4,0)   coordinate[label=below:L] (l)
            to ["${P(r,\theta)}$" ']  ++ (120:4) coordinate (r2);
% angles at x-axis
\pic [Angle, "$\theta$"]    {angle = x--o--r1};
\pic [Angle, "$\phi$"]      {angle = x--l--r2};
% intersection with angles
\path [name intersections={of=A and B, by=i}]
    pic [Angle, "$\beta$"]     {angle = r1--i--r2}
    pic [Angle, "$\beta$"]     {angle = o--i--l};
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for the excellent additional answer

Answer (score 5):

Using the [`tzplot`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tzplot) package:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
    
\usepackage{tzplot}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\scriptsize]
\tzaxes*(-.5,-.5)(5,5){$X$}{$Y$}
\tzcoors(4,0)(L)(2.5,4)(B)(0,0)(O)(3.5,4)(D);
\tzline[thick]"LB"(L){$P(r,\theta)$}[pos=.4,r](B)
\tzline[thick]"OD"(O){$r$}[pos=.4,l](D)
\tzXpoint{LB}{OD}(X)
\tzanglemark[<->](B)(X)(D){$\phi$}[pos=1.3](6mm)
\tzanglemark[<->](L)(X)(O){$\phi$}[pos=1.3](6mm)
\tzanglemark[<->](L)(O)(D){$\theta$}[pos=1.3](6mm)
\tzanglemark[<->](5,0)(L)(B){$\Psi$}[pos=1.3](6mm)
\tznode(L){$L$}[br]
\tznode(O){$O$}[bl]
\tznode(2,1){$r=f(\theta)$}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```